# Yii CRUD render mysql date view

Tags: yii

The gii CRUD generator automatically generates in _form view a text field. Is it possible to automatically generate 3 dropdown lists, one for year, month and day?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there are any automated generations for that. Check out CJuiDatePicker if using that can be an option. If not, you will need to generate the values for the dropdowns and set them in dropdowns the manual way.